# Why did this character join the Mossad?

Tags: character, the-blacklist

The character Samar Navabi is Iranian by birth, so what motivated her to sign on with an Israeli intelligence agency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the show we learn that she was recruited by Mossad.

From [The Blacklist wikia](http://the-blacklist.wikia.com/wiki/Samar_Navabi),

> Samar Navabi is a Mossad operative who has had past interactions with
>   Raymond Reddington. With the death of Meera Malik, she is assigned by
>   Deputy Director Cooper to the task force as an investigative agent and
>   Mossad liaison.
>
> She is an Iranian-born Baloch, we learn, who was radicalized and, one
>   assumes, recruited by Mossad because of the mistreatment and killing
>   of her parents by the Iranian regime.

further readings > [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Blacklist_characters#Samar_Navabi)

In the episode "Zal Bin Hassan", Samar's past is revealed and how she witnessed the death of her parents. She joined mossad to find and get her parents' killer to justice.

Comment: "Mossad is also Iranian" is plain wrong. What gave you this wrong impression? (Mossad is an [Israeli intelligence agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mossad), as OP said in the question)

Comment: Well, not wrong now, thanks. But the answer doesn't address the question, i.e. it doesn't explain why she agreed to join it. The fact she joined is known; the reason isn't known. (According to the question, I didn't watch it.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard She wanted to find who murdered her parents.

Comment: So better make it more clear, not just quote something and let the reader try and figure it out themselves. ;)